# SQL SERVER FK and Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl

I'm working with SQL SERVER 2000 and I have this code for creating a table. My table has foreign keys and I wish to add a constraint.
My Question is: Must I define the constraint AND the foreign key? or is just one of them enough?

```
CREATE TABLE controls
(
id                  INT         IDENTITY(1,1)   PRIMARY KEY,
description         VARCHAR(2000),
date                DATETIME,
result              VARCHAR(255),
clients_id          INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES clients(id),
profesionals_id     INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES profesionals(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTS   FOREIGN KEY (clients_id) REFERENCES clients(id)
);
```

The last 2 lines, FK definition and Constraint, is it redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line

```
CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTS   FOREIGN KEY (clients_id) REFERENCES clients(id)
```

Is equivalent to the iniline definition following `client_ids`:

```
FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES clients(id)
```

One of the two should be removed.

Comment: I'd usually recommend keeping the `CONSTRAINT` variant and removing the inline declaration; the inline variant still gives it a name but it's completely unpredictable which makes for bad times if you later need to write a script that needs to (temporarily) remove the constraint.